# PutDatabaseRecord failed with Index header CSVRecord

Tags: postgresql, csv, apache-nifi

We are trying to insert data to postgresql based database.

We use PutDatabaseRecord processor with following configurations :

[image: Record Reader]

But we get an warning and data is not inserted to database and records are not inserted.

Is this apache commoncsv related issue?

How can I solve this issue?

Edit :

After @matt's initial answer : I found intersting thing with data, in address field it has :

`"No 60, Marine Drive,"`

CSVReader in PutDatabaseRecord uses `,` value separator. So address must be read as 3 different column values.

Comment: Can you share the CSV header line and a few lines of data?

Comment: @mattyb unfortunately, I can not do that. extremely sorry about it.

Comment: @mattyb I have updated the question, I found something interesting with a column.

Comment: You should be able to set the Quote Character in the reader to `"` so it won't think those commas are field separators

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to indicate you have more columns in the header than in (some lines of) data. If that's not the case, I suspect there's either a bug when handling empty columns, or `Infer Schema` doesn't work as expected with an empty column in the first row (how would it be able to guess the type of "nothing"?).

Comment: Yes, we do have empty data columns. But first row always have some data with separated with `,`. as an example :
`455,sdas,,8588,A887,,ssd,4`

Comment: Can you specify the schema explicitly instead of using `Infer Schema` for the reader?

Comment: what do you mean by "schema explicitly instead of using Infer Schema for the reader" ??

Comment: In the CSVReader your `Schema Access Strategy` property is set to `Infer Schema`. Instead you can set it to `Use Schema Text` and populate the `Schema Text` property with an Avro schema that corresponds to the columns in the CSV files, including making fields optional/nullable.